# Probability of a special polynomial to be zero in $\mathbb{F}_q$

Tags: probability

Given two primes $p,q$ ; $p<q$ and $1 \leq r < p$

Consider the following polynomial $$  f(x)={p\choose{i}} x^{p-i} + {p\choose{i+r}} x^{p-(i+r)} + \ldots {p\choose{i+kr}} x^{p-(i+kr)} \qquad{} \mbox{till ($i+kr  < p$)}$$

If I pick a random $x \in \mathbb{F}_q$ , what is the probability that it is **not** a root of $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{F}_q$?

I want to prove that this probability is atleast constant $``c" \forall i$.

Where $c$ is independent of $p$ and $q$.

Comment: @Crostul I meant **not** a root with constant probability.